# How to get previous 'div' ( 'div' just above current 'div')

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

my HTML is as below

```
<div style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt">
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="center"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold"><font style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; DISPLAY: inline">PART II</font></font></div>

<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="justify">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold"><font style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; DISPLAY: inline">ITEM 5. MARKET FOR REGISTRANT’S COMMON EQUITY AND RELATED STOCKHOLDER MATTERS.</font></font></div>

<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="justify">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"><font style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; DISPLAY: inline">Our common stock is quoted on the OTCBB under the symbol UOIP. The reported high and low closing prices for the common stock as reported on the OTCBB are shown below for the periods indicated. The quotations reflect inter-dealer prices, without retail mark-up, markdown or commission, and may not represent actual transactions.</font></font></div>

<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="left">&nbsp;</div>

<div align="left">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="bottom" style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp; </font></td>
<td valign="bottom" style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td colspan="2" valign="bottom" style="BORDER-BOTTOM: black 2px solid">
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="center"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">High</font></div>
</td>
<td nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td valign="bottom" style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td colspan="2" valign="bottom" style="BORDER-BOTTOM: black 2px solid">
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="center"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Low</font></div>
</td>
<td nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left" valign="bottom">
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Nine months ended June 30, 2014</font></div>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="bottom"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td align="left" colspan="2" valign="bottom"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td align="left" valign="bottom"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td align="left" colspan="2" valign="bottom"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr><tr bgcolor="#cceeff">
<td align="left" valign="bottom" width="76%">
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">First quarter ended December 31, 2013</font></div>
</td>
<td align="right" valign="bottom" width="1%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td valign="bottom" width="1%" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">$</font></td>
<td valign="bottom" width="9%" style="TEXT-ALIGN: right"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">12.4000</font></td>
<td nowrap="" valign="bottom" width="1%" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td align="right" valign="bottom" width="1%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
<td valign="bottom" width="1%" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">$</font></td>
<td valign="bottom" width="9%" style="TEXT-ALIGN: right"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">3.6400</font></td>
<td nowrap="" valign="bottom" width="1%" style="TEXT-ALIGN: left"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>
```

i have located the table using `find_all('table')`. How can i get any previous `div`s which has text (or any data / not blank).  (one which is previous to the div which has the table)

I have tried `find_previous('div')` , but didn't work. Please help.

Comment: my guess is if you are using `find_all()`, you need to specify the index of the table

Comment: @chitown88, there is only one table ,

Comment: then don't use `find_all()`, just use `find()`. Find all will return to you a list. Even if that is a list of 1 element

Comment: @chitown88, ok , got it. but how to fid the previous `div` to the one in which table is?

Comment: what are you after? the `<div align="left">`?

Comment: `<div align="left">` is the `div` in which the table is, i want to get the one above which has a text 'Our common stock is quoted on the OTCBB under the symbol UOIP'

Comment: I just posted below in the solution for ya

Comment: how many div align=left are there? You might use div[align=left] ~ div[align=left]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
prev_div = table.find_previous('div').find_previous('div').find_previous('div').text
```

or

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')
prev_div = table[0].find_previous('div').find_previous('div').find_previous('div').text
```

**Output:**

```
'Our common stock is quoted on the OTCBB under the symbol UOIP. The reported high and low closing prices for the common stock as reported on the OTCBB are shown below for the periods indicated. The quotations reflect inter-dealer prices, without retail mark-up, markdown or commission, and may not represent actual transactions.'
```

Comment: Thank you, i was finding the previous div of the table, which was giving the same div  in which the table is.

Comment: ya it's tricky with the multiple divs. I haven't used find_previous much, so there might be a more elegant way, but it gets the job done